# Apache 2.4 sending Expires header but not 304 status (DEBIAN)

Tags: apache, debian, apache2.4

I'm scratching my head on this one.

I have the following:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 hours"
Header append Cache-Control "public"
```

The response clearly acknowledges the new header and a Expires header in the future,  ☝️BUT returns 200 instead of 304. Same setting on local Mac (Apache 2.4.xx) and on FreeBSD return 304. Any ideas?

Both the expires and header module are installed. What could I be missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When mod_expires is working, you generally won't see a 304 at all because the client doesn't need to bother sending a subsequent, conditional request.

On a basic site, a 304 occurs when the client asks if e.g. /foo.css from a previous timestamp or ETAG is still the latest.  304 means yes, 200 means no (and here's the replacement).

Once you add mod_expires, you're telling them to not even bother asking again.